# Ordenar elementos entre divs com drag e drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde.

Eu estou fazendo um projeto pessoal e nele eu tenho varias divs com divs dentro e preciso conseguir trocar esses elementos uns com os outros, consigo colocar um elemento que está na col-1 com o que está na col-2 por exemplo, em um range de um, ou seja, apenas consigo trocar um elemento com aqueles que fazem fronteira com ele mesmo.
Sou novo com jQuery e estou perdido em como fazer usando draggable() e droppable().

O código de como estão estruturadas as divs é o seguinte.

```
<div class="painel-tabuleiro">
  <div class="col-1">
      <div class="containerImg">
          <img class="elemento" src="imagem/1.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="containerImg">
          <img class="elemento" src="imagem/1.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="containerImg">
          <img class="elemento" src="imagem/1.png"/>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
      <div class="containerImg">
          <img class="elemento" src="imagem/2.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="containerImg">
          <img class="elemento" src="imagem/2.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="containerImg">
          <img class="elemento" src="imagem/2.png"/>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
      <div class="containerImg">
          <img class="elemento" src="imagem/3.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="containerImg">
          <img class="elemento" src="imagem/3.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="containerImg">
          <img class="elemento" src="imagem/3.png"/>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript feito. Não utilizei jQuery aqui e este script não faz a troca pois não estou sabendo como pegar o local de onde a imagem saiu.

```
var elements = [];

function dragUser(element, event) {
    var index = elements.indexOf(element);
    if (index == -1) {
        // not already existing in the array, add it now
        elements.push(element);
        index = elements.length - 1;
    }
    event.dataTransfer.setData('index', index);
}

function dropUser(target, event) {
    var element = elements[event.dataTransfer.getData('index')];
    target.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Você tentou fazer algum código com o jQuery? se sim adicione na sua pergunta

Comment: tive a mesma dúvida esses dias, utilizei JQuery me embasando neste link: https://alexrosa.net/ordenacao-com-jquery-sortable/ Tem um vídeo do YouTube explicando aí também.

Comment: @sant0will postei o JS ja feito. Ele realiza a mudança da imagem normalmente caso a div de destino esteja vazia, mas se conter outra imagem, estou sem saber como realizar a troca de imagens.

Comment: Como são usadas essas funções?

Comment: as opções já prontas nao te atendem? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/